# is sentence "But deep learning is also enabling brand new products and businesses and ways of helping people to be created. " corrent in grammar?

Tags: grammar

I feel kind of confusion about

> But deep learning is also enabling brand new products and businesses
> and **ways of helping people to be created**.

I don't know how to understand "ways of helping people to be created."

I think "deep learning is also enabling brand new products and businesses" is easy to understand.
as well as "deep learning is also enabling brand new products and businesses

what make me feel confuse is to be created.If I abstract the subsentence from it, it becames:

> deep learning is enabling ways of helping people to be created.

I think it's maybe a unclear way to expression.

Comment: Maybe a misprint for _creative_?

Comment: I feel **confused about x**. Helping people to be creative, not created.

Comment: What part of the grammar are you unclear about? Do you recognize that "ways of helping people to be created" is a noun phrase, the direct object of "enabling"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is because "to be created" doesn't go with "people" but with "enabling." Written out in a longer form, the sentence could be

> But deep learning is also enabling brand new products and businesses to be created, and it is enabling brand new ways of helping people to be created."

It's a compound verb with multiple objects. For a simpler parallel, it's like saying "A mixer lets cakes and pies and brownies be prepared."

One thing that's awkward about this sentence, if not an actual mistake, is that there are three objects and the writer separates them all with "and," instead of saying "... enabling brand new products, businesses, and ways of helping people...." That's probably because they thought of "products and businesses" as being related, a single thing, but I don't think that makes sense. It would make sense if they were *often* paired, like "research and development."

Comment: It helps people to be ***created***? Surely that's a typo for "creative".

Comment: @gotube "enabling new ways-of-helping-people to be created." I had another paragraph about other ways the sentence is clunky but decided to delete it.

Comment: OOOF! That would be terrible writing, but it just might be the intended meaning.

Comment: @gotube I'm pretty sure it is. A much more elegant sentence would be "But deep learning is also letting us create new products, businesses, and ways of helping people." I'm guessing it opts for passive voice since... well, strictly speaking it's not *we* who are doing the creating, I guess.

Comment: That's the meaning I got to - but only after reading it three times. enabling [ways of helping people] to be created.